# Git show upstream of moved file

Tags: git

If I have a file that's been renamed several times, and a known revision, and I need to see its state at a given revision -- how would I map the current filename and revision to the old filename?   `git show` does not seem to be smart enough:

```
git show $rev:dir1/file1.c
fatal: path 'dir1/file1.c' exists on disk, but not in 'a1b86bcbe9bb27f17ddf3c895135def0d366e0a0'
```

---

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
tmp> echo hi > dir0/file2.c
tmp> git add dir0/file2.c; git commit -m "First commit"
[master 8c34d4f] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dir0/file2.c
tmp> git mv dir0/file2.c dir1/file2.c
tmp> git commit -m "moving file"
[master 7181e5b] moving file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename {dir0 => dir1}/file2.c (100%)
tmp> echo Hello >> dir1/file2.c
tmp> git add -u; git commit -m "Last Commit"
[master 799192b] Last Commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
tmp> git show HEAD^^:dir1/file2.c
fatal: path 'dir1/file2.c' exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD^^'
```

Comment: Did you rename it using `git`? Or via some other means? Provide all your steps in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I moved it using git (`git mv dir0/file1.c dir1/file1.c`)

Comment: Provide all your steps in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Ok...   added an MRE...    The real life situation is of course much more complicated, and is part of a script, so it has to handle corner cases.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure this is meaningful in its current form: you're asking git for "dir1/file2.c" as it was found in `HEAD^^`, which it wasn't. You may need to `log` the file on disk and `--follow` it back to `HEAD^^` then pull out the path it had at the time (if any).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking about.   How do you map a current filename to an older filename at a given commit-id?   (Note that this is a script, and I don't want to be parsing the output of `git log --follow`)

Comment: You may be stuck then. The information about the move is part of the revision history, which suggests you need the log for it.

Comment: (I prefer how SVN does this, with pin revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git diff` with `--find-renames` enabled.  (Or, `git log --follow`, which does the same thing internally.)  For programmatic consumption consider using `git diff-tree` or one of the other so-called plumbing commands, which have well-defined output formats.  Besides `-M` (short for `--find-renames`), consider using the `--diff-filter` and/or `-z` flags as well.  You can compare two commits directly, or go commit-by-commit as `git log` does; see the long description below.

#### Long

> If I have a file that's been renamed several times, and a known revision, and I need to see its state at a given revision -- how would I map the current filename and revision to the old filename?

There is no easy and perfect answer to this.

The problem you're looking at here is [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(philosophy)): what does it mean for file X to be "the same file" as file Y?  In some systems, there are easy (but eventually always unsatisfactory) answers.  For instance, we can assign an "inode number" to file X.  If we then rename file X without changing its "inode number", we can, later, scan all our files to find those with the old inode number.  Whatever name(s) turn up, those are the names of file X.  All we have really done, though, is claim that the *true* name of "file X" is its inode number, and that we use false names—aliases of some sort—which we look up in some sort of table (hidden or not) to find its true name, by which we access the true file.

The *reason* this is unsatisfactory is that we can then take the *entire content* of the file with this constant inode number and move it all to some other file with some other inode number.  Because it's the internal inode number that determines identity, we now think that this empty file is the right file.  But we rename this empty file to "X.defunct" and rename the new-inode-number file to "X" so that all the *contents* are plainly visible, right there in a file named X, yet our system insists that the *real* X is the one with no content.  Our [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) has rotted away, and yet, right there in the harbor, there's the Ship of Theseus for everyone to see.

When Linus Torvalds was writing Git, he was aware of these issues and decided that the Correct Method was *not* to depend on either of the two most common methods.  Most VCSes use either file names, or some sort of internal identity number (an "inode number" or equivalent), to track individual files.  Git does not do so.  Instead, each commit simply records *every* file, as of the form it has at the time the commit is made.

Later, if we pick any pair of commits, Git will (in principle at least):

- extract the two entire commits somewhere; then
- compare the *contents* of *every file* to the contents of *every other file*.

In this way, if, for instance, some function `f` was in `lib` and some function `g` was also in `lib`, but `f` is now in `lib_part_1` and `g` is now in `lib_part_2`, we can decide that the `f` in one file is the same as the `f` in another file, and the `g` in one file is the same as the `g` in a *third* file.

For computability (i.e., performance) reasons, given current technologies, Git doesn't actually do all of this in practice every time.  Some commands, such as `git blame`, are more willing to reach across multiple files than others, such as `git diff`.  But overall, that's the general idea: we do not constrain ourselves to specific *files* but rather look for specific *content*.  As computers get faster, we get to change how the content analysis works.

For now, though, the way it works in `git diff` is kind of [cheesy (see meaning 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheesy).  Given two commits *L* and *R* (for left and right), Git starts by looking at all the file names in the two commits.  If both *L* and *R* have a file whose name is `path/to/file.ext`, Git assumes, at least for starting purposes, that this is "the same file".  These files are identified as "the same file" despite the fact that the contents might differ.

If files have been renamed, however, we usually find that there is some file in *L* that has no corresponding name at all in *R*, and vice versa.  By comparing the contents of the gone-from-*L*-new-in-*R* files (all of them, pairwise), Git can *figure out* whether some file was renamed.

Because of Git's internal storage format, Git first does a fast check to see if some files exactly match.  If so, they get paired up: identified as "the same file".  These identified pairs come out of the set of unmatched files in *L* and *R*.  Only the remaining files get their contents analyzed.  Each proposed pairing is assigned a *similarity index*, which is a percentage score.  Any pairing that meets some minimum threshold is retained, and then the best such pairing is used to identify files on *L* and *R* as "the same".

What all this means is that if you take any pair of commits and compare them, if some files were renamed but their contents are "sufficiently similar", Git will declare them to be renamed.  This renaming comes with a similarity index value that ranges from 1 (almost entirely different—zero means entirely different and won't pair) to 100 (exactly the same).  Computing these scores is expensive, so it only happens if you enable rename-finding.  There is also a limit on the rename queue length as the comparison compares m⋅n possible pairs (m files on the left, n on the right).<sup>1</sup>

What this all means, then, is that in general, we can do:

```
git diff --find-renames <revision-L> <revision-R>
```

and Git will turn on the rename detector and try to guess if some file in *L* whose name does not exist in *R* matches some file in *R* whose name does not exist in *L*.  If some *other* file got created, so that the names exist in both revisions, the rename detector will be defeated.  If the file got changed too much, the rename detector will also be defeated, but we can lower the required score.  This does, however, raise the risk of detecting a rename erroneously due to matching some irrelevant parts of some files.  If we get bad matches, we can raise the required score past the default 50%.

Adding `--name-status` makes `git diff` not print out an actual diff, but rather just the file names and status letters.  Status letter `R` is reserved for renames, and includes the score and both the old and new names.

Adding `--diff-filter` makes `git diff` print only the diffs (or names) where the diff *status* letter is the letter we select, so `git diff --find-renames --diff-filter=R --name-status` gets us what we want (though there might be multiple renames detected here).

The `git log --follow` code simply runs `git diff` on each parent/child pair in the revision stream, one step at a time, working backwards from the latest commit, with the rename detector turned on ... while also looking for one particular file.  Upon finding the file, if the rename detector shows a rename, when `git log` steps from the child to the parent, it starts looking for the old name instead of the new name.  If commits contain relatively small changes—and/or if renames are committed separately from all other changes—this can very quickly find the renamed file, due to the shortcut mentioned above, but it does require stepping through *all* the revisions.

The `git diff` method lets us cut out all the intermediaries: we just pick one revision to be on the left, and another to be on the right.  We don't even need to put the older one on the left (though there's no reason to prefer it the other way either).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the porcelain `diff` command obeys the user's `diff.renames` and `diff.renameLimit` settings, while the plumbing commands require command-line options to set these.  The default values for `diff` were changed several times over the last two decades, and now default to "on" and 400.

Comment: I very much appreciate the detailed answer and explanation.  I had been under the impression that a `git mv` would store meta-data in the repository indicating what was moved from where, but by your description it doesn't sound like that happens. 
  I modified my script to parse `git diff --find-renames --name-status,`, and it seems to do the job, though I understand there may be corner cases going forward.

Comment: Yes, Git doesn't care how the renaming might have occurred (there's no special metadata for that—nothing like the file numbers inside ClearCase, for instance). For scripting purposes I'd recommend switching to `git diff-tree` or `git diff-index`: you'll need to add `-r` but can drop `--name-status`, and the output is guaranteed to be machine readable and not change on you (not true for the porcelain `git diff` front end).